# Excel formula - Is there a way to perform if statements for same query cell for nth cells before changing to next consecutive query cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a sheet1 that has the following dataset A

```
ColumnA:    ColumnB:      ColumnC:      ColumnD:

Row1:        June 1        June 2        June 3
Row2:
Row3: A      Apple         Apple         Orange
Row4: B      Orange        Orange        Orange
Row5: C      Orange        Apple         Orange
Row6: D      Pear          Apple         Pear
```

In that sheet I have the following table

```
       Consumed fruits
        **June 1**             **June 2**            **June 3**
     Apple Orange Pear      Apple Orange Pear     Apple Orange Pear

A    True                   True                        True
B          True                   True                  True
C          True             True                        True
D                 True      True                               True
```

Where for each cell I add the following code that pertains to datasetA

For June 1, A, Apple

```
=IF(B3="Apple","True","")
```

June 1, A, Orange

```
=IF(B3="Orange","True","")
```

June 1,A, Pear

```
=IF(B3="Pear","True","")
```

But when I drag the formula to the next date (June 2, A, Apple), it changes to

```
=IF(B6="Apple","True","")
```

Instead of

```
=IF(B4="Apple","True","")
```

Is there anyway to keep the query cells constant for 3 formulas, before incrementing just one query cell up in the next 3 formulas?

Comment: In a small database you can use INDIRECT(ADDRESS()). But this is a volatile function which will slow down your workbook. Hence not recommended for a larger book. A non-volatile solution would involve the use of INDEX(). If your data are in a real table the range to be indexed already exists. Else you would have to set it up and you would use a dynamic named range for that purpose. Is your data in a table? Do you know how to set up a dynamic named range?

Comment: Hi Variatus. Thank you for your reply. Yes my data is in a table. Sheet1 contains dataA, and I was hoping to create a table in Sheet2 that would have a tally of all the data in Sheet1. No, I don't know how to set up a dynamic range - I only know basic excel formulas - so any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the formula. It's in B11 on the screenshot below and copied from there to B11:J14.

```
=IF(INDEX(Table1,MATCH($A11,Table1[Column1],0),MATCH(TEXT(INDEX($9:$9,0,COLUMN()-MOD(COLUMN()-2,3)),"mmm-dd"),Table1[#Headers],0))=B$10,TRUE,"")
```

[image]

The formulas in B16:B20 are components of the final formula. I used them for testing. They may help you understands what the formula does. Here's some more help toward that end.

The basic syntax of the INDEX() function is `INDEX([Range address], [Row number], [Column number])`. The range can be a named range, such as "Table1". Row and column numbers can be hard numbers but are supplied by MATCH() functions in my formula.

Excel stores a date, such as `Jun-01`, as a number, counting days from December 30, 1899. In the table headers, however, Excel converted the dates to strings. Therefore the value of cell B1 is "Jun-01", just what you see, but the value of cell B9 is 37043 which is the number for Jun 01, 2001. The year was supplied by Excel because I didn't enter any year (I was expecting it to furnish the current year 2020 but that doesn't matter here). In order to find the date in the table headers the real date in B9 is converted to a string with `TEXT(B9,"mmm-dd")` where the year is disregarded. That string is used by the MATCH function to find the correct table column using values in row 9 for examples. Of course, if you don't have real dates in your equivalent of row 9 but strings my formula won't work because the conversion isn't needed. Take it out.

So, row 9 is important to my formula. Look for `$9:$9` and change this reference to the row where you have the dates in your output table (A9:J14 in my picture). If your output table is a real table the sheet reference will work but you may want to change it to something like `Table2[#Headers]`. If you do this some adjustment to columns may also be required.

Place the formula `=MOD(COLUMN()-2,3)` in a blank row and copy to the right. if you pasted the original in column B it will produce a series of repetitions of 0, 1 and 2. These are used to always refer to the first column of a set of 3, like, *COLUMN()-0*, *COLUMN()-1* and *COLUMN()-2*. In this formula, `COLUMN()-2` is particular to sheet column B. The formula produces a 0 in column B. Change this number so that the formula produces a zero in the column in which you have the date. Test with this component and carry the change to the big formula after you know that it works the way it should. Note that if the date is in merged cells, Excel stores it in the first cell of the merged area. The other cells are blank as far as Excel is concerned.

I hope you will be able to take command of this formnula. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thank you for the thorough explanation! Its really good and handy. Ive been playing around with the different parts of the formula to see if I get it. I run into the problem of when I try dragging it, this part ```MATCH($A11,Table1[Column1],0)``` becomes ```MATCH($A11,Table1[Jun-01],0)``` and it produces an #N/A in the cell

Answer (score 1):

Or,

In `B11` copied across right to `J11` and all copied down :

```
=IF(INDEX($B$3:$D$6,MATCH($A11,$A$3:$A$6,0),MATCH(LOOKUP(9^9,$B$9:B$9),$B$1:$D$1,0))=B$10,TRUE,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi bosco_yip! This worked perfectly too! Thank you!